# Redmon postscript output

Tags: c#, redmon

I'm using the [redmon](http://www.ghostgum.com.au/software/redmon.htm) to redirect de output [postcript](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) my c# `.exe` to process.
The print configuration is the same as if I'd do to configure the [ghostscript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Wi03U7qiFM&feature=youtu.be), but instead of the ghost path I informed my `.exe` path.

[image]

To convert the postscript in PDF I'm using the [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/), as the code bellow

```
Stream content = Console.OpenStandardInput();
using BinaryReader standardInputReader = new BinaryReader(content);

using (FileStream standardInputFile = new FileStream(psFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    standardInputReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(standardInputFile);
}
standardInputReader.Close();

string ghostScriptPath = @"C:\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64.exe";

String ars = @"-Ic:\gs\gs925\lib -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=teste.pdf psFile.ps";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ars;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

But the `ghostscript` always throws the error **%%[ Error: undefined; OffendingCommand: Redmon ]%%**.

If I use the ghostscript instead of my program everything works fine, but if I "intercept", the error always happens. I logged the output on the two cases, but the log is the same, a piece bellow.

The full log can be seen [here](http://github.com/marinauliano/postscript/blob/master/redmon-log.ps)

```
%%BeginResource: file Pscript_WinNT_ErrorHandler 5.0 0
/currentpacking where{pop/oldpack currentpacking def/setpacking where{pop false
setpacking}if}if/$brkpage 64 dict def $brkpage begin/prnt{dup type/stringtype
ne{=string cvs}if dup length 6 mul/tx exch def/ty 10 def currentpoint/toy exch
def/tox exch def 1 setgray newpath tox toy 2 sub moveto 0 ty rlineto tx 0
rlineto 0 ty neg rlineto closepath fill tox toy moveto 0 setgray show}bind def
/nl{currentpoint exch pop lmargin exch moveto 0 -10 rmoveto}def/=={/cp 0 def
typeprint nl}def/typeprint{dup type exec}readonly def/lmargin 72 def/rmargin 72
def/tprint{dup length cp add rmargin gt{nl/cp 0 def}if dup length cp add/cp
exch def prnt}readonly def/cvsprint{=string cvs tprint( )tprint}readonly def
/integertype{cvsprint}readonly def/realtype{cvsprint}readonly def/booleantype
{cvsprint}readonly def/operatortype{(--)tprint =string cvs tprint(-- )tprint}
readonly def/marktype{pop(-mark- )tprint}readonly def/dicttype{pop
(-dictionary- )tprint}readonly def/nulltype{pop(-null- )tprint}readonly def
/filetype{pop(-filestream- )tprint}readonly def/savetype{pop(-savelevel- )
tprint}readonly def/fonttype{pop(-fontid- )tprint}readonly def/nametype{dup
xcheck not{(/)tprint}if cvsprint}readonly def/stringtype{dup rcheck{(\()tprint
tprint(\))tprint}{pop(-string- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/arraytype{dup rcheck
{dup xcheck{({)tprint{typeprint}forall(})tprint}{([)tprint{typeprint}forall(])
tprint}ifelse}{pop(-array- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/packedarraytype{dup
rcheck{dup xcheck{({)tprint{typeprint}forall(})tprint}{([)tprint{typeprint}
forall(])tprint}ifelse}{pop(-packedarray- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/courier
/Courier findfont 10 scalefont def end errordict/handleerror{systemdict begin
$error begin $brkpage begin newerror{/newerror false store vmstatus pop pop 0
ne{grestoreall}if errorname(VMerror)ne{showpage}if initgraphics courier setfont
lmargin 720 moveto errorname(VMerror)eq{userdict/ehsave known{clear userdict
/ehsave get restore 2 vmreclaim}if vmstatus exch pop exch pop PrtVMMsg}{
(ERROR: )prnt errorname prnt nl(OFFENDING COMMAND: )prnt/command load prnt
$error/ostack known{nl nl(STACK:)prnt nl nl $error/ostack get aload length{==}
repeat}if}ifelse systemdict/showpage get exec(%%[ Error: )print errorname
=print(; OffendingCommand: )print/command load =print( ]%%)= flush}if end end
end}dup 0 systemdict put dup 4 $brkpage put bind readonly put/currentpacking
where{pop/setpacking where{pop oldpack setpacking}if}if
%%EndResource
```

> obs: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: There is not enough there to help you. All you've supplied is the standard error handler from the Windows PostScript printer driver. I presume that this only occurs when you start Ghostscript as a process from your own program (why are you doing this anyway?). You should start by testing Ghostscript at the shell with the command line from your application. Does that work ? If so then its something about your code. If it does not then its something to do with the input to Ghostscript. If its the latter then put the file somewhere public and link it here.

Comment: Hi, I tested at the shell, but the same problem occur. The full log that readmon created it's here https://github.com/marinauliano/postscript/blob/master/redmon-log.ps

Answer (score 0):

OK well if you look at the file you posted it begins:

```
RedMon - Redirection Port Monitor
Copyright (C) 1997-2012, Ghostgum Software Pty Ltd.  All Rights Reserved.
2012-06-21  Version 1.9

get_filename_as_user sent: C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\teste.pdf
....
...
REDMON WritePort: about to write 4096 bytes to port.
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
```

Everything up to the `%!PS-Adobe` is not PostScript and is not being sent by the printer driver. That's all being sent by the RedMon Port Monitor. The output then ends with:

```
%%EOF

REDMON WritePort: OK  count=2489 written=2489
REDMON EndDocPort: starting

REDMON WriteThread: ending
%%[Page: 1]%%
%%[LastPage]%%
REDMON EndDocPort: process finished after 1 second

REDMON EndDocPort: 0 bytes written to printer
REDMON EndDocPort: ending
```

and there everything following the %%EOF is not PostScript and is coming from the Port Monitor. Since all of that doesn't form a valid PostScript program, sending it to Ghostscript will cause an error of some kind.

You need to work out how to strip that verbiage out and only send the PostScript language program to Ghostscript.

I'm afraid I can't help you with that, I don't know how your application is receiving data from RedMon.

In any event this isn't really a Ghostscript, or PostScript, question.

Comment: Well, I know that. When I do my tests I remove this parts and when I read the output from readmon directly, the output doesn't have this parts you know.

Comment: Well you didn't **say** that. What I want to see is the input file as you send it to Ghostscript. Whether that be by spawning a process from your application or the shell command line isn't important. Its the content of the PostScript program I need to see. So if you are stripping out content, then please post what it is you actually send to Ghostscript.